# Should I use Promise.All instead of async.each?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently using async.each to build array. I wonder if there is alternative approach using es6? Should I use Promise.All?

```
async pushDataArray(response) {
    if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
        async.each(response.data, (data, error) => {
            if (this.messagesData.length < this.maxCount) {
                this.messagesData.push(data);
            }
        });
    }

    return this.messagesData;
}
```

Usage:

```
await this.pushDataArray(response);
```

Comment: Is there a *problem* with async.each?

Comment: I don't like to take on dependencies, especially when there's a native solution, but when it comes to JS I ride Roman. YMMV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not use neither. There is nothing asynchronous in your code. Just write

```
pushDataArray(response) {
    if (response && response.data) {
        for (const data of response.data) {
            if (this.messagesData.length < this.maxCount) {
                this.messagesData.push(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return this.messagesData;
}
```

or even simpler

```
pushDataArray(response) {
    if (response && response.data) {
        this.messagesData.push(...response.data.slice(0, this.maxCount - this.messagesData.length));
    }
    return this.messagesData;
}
```

Comment: I was scratching my head on what was async in the code, well, nothing was haha.

Comment: Thank you. what about using `response.data.ForEach(data => {})` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I don't like `forEach`, it has no good purpose. A normal loop is much more idiomatic and works in more contexts.

Comment: Are you sure `this.maxCount - response.data.length` is correct? Don't you mean check the `messagesData` length

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Yes, you're totally right. Fixed it, thanks!